# Identifying system to represent output data as combination of 3 input data

Tags: matlab, system-identification

I have some numerical data, which has 3 input vectors and 1 output vector. I have to use all the inputs to represent the output. I am new to dsp and struggling to understand how to do this.

X1: Mostly -80 to 80. Few outliers till +/-100 or +/-200
X2: Mostly -4 to 4. 
X3: Mostly -1 to 1. Most are 0.0 something.

The data is not supposed to be considered noisy. It is a observation based data, not so much of a signal. (I don't know if that is the correct term)

I tried the least square method and got a very different output.

```
w1 = corr(X1, Y)
w2 = corr(X2, Y)
w3 = corr(X3, Y)

for epoch = 1:epochs
        for n = 1:length(Y)
            % n
            Y_pred = w1*X1(n) + w2*X2(n) + w3*X3(n) + b; % initial predicted y
            Y_loss_grad = 2*(Y_pred - Y(n)); % gradient of sqaure error

            % update the weights
            % w = w-lr*(loss_grad*y_grad)
            w1 = w1-lr*( Y_loss_grad*X1(n) );
            w2 = w2-lr*( Y_loss_grad*X2(n) );
            w3 = w3-lr*( Y_loss_grad*X3(n) );
```

By varying epochs and learning rate, I finally set `epochs = 100` and `lr = 0.0003`. Any more epochs and there are unnecessary iterations and even a slightly higher learning rate and the `Y_loss_grad` eventually goes to `-inf` and then `NaN`. Below is the output.

```
weight of X1: 6.988717
weight of X2: 1.613900
weight of X3: 596.504787

The model error is 267408804.091201
```

[image: Multiple linear regression]

I tried [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/signal-approximation-using-linear-combination-of-functions) which got me this output.
[image: What the original output is supposed to be (no negatives)]
[image: What I'm getting using lsm (lot of it is negavtive)]

I have another idea, where I take fft of each input, pass a certain filter over each and sum them. Then get the error with the fft of output vector, calculate the gradient w.r.t each input vector fft and adjust the filter of each input vector fft using that gradient.

The problems I'm facing in this idea are:

1. What filter to use? (low, high, band) (butterworth, chebyshev etc). Additionally the same filter might not work with each input.
2. How to adjust the filter? Do I change the order, the cut-off/pass frequencies?
3. Does optimizing using error in the frequency domain even help in the time domain?
4. If yes how do I change it back to the time domain to get the x[n]*h[n] = y[n], where x[n] is 3 values (1 from each input vector at n).

Any explanation about concepts, what steps to take or direction to useful resources would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please suggest tags for better reach

Comment: Are all 4 vectors the same length and data type?

Comment: @Vorac Yes, all 4 vectors have the same length. The same row number in all 3 represents a single observation. As for datatype, if you mean double, int types, these are all double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regression approach seems to be needless complicated. Let's look at this step by step"

First you need to start with a model. A simple linear model would be

$$y[n] = w_1x_1[n] + w_2x_2[n] + w_3x_3[n]$$

Going forward I'm going drop the $[n]$ for quicker typing and all sum symbols mean "sum over all n".

Then define an error metric. For example

$$E = \sum (w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3-y)^2$$

Then calculate the partial derivatives of the error to each model parameters and set them to zero

Example
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial w_1} = 2\sum  x_1 \cdot(w_1\sum x_1 + w_2 \sum x_2 + w_3 \sum x_3 - \sum y) = 0 $$

Do this for all model parameters. This will give your three equations with three unknowns which you need to solve. In this example these are just three linear equations, so that should be solvable without too much trouble. No need for regression, this can be solved in a single step.

However, your data does not look like a linear model: your output is all positive but your input appears to be double sided and maybe even symmetric to 0. Linear models typically don't do that, so changes are you need a more complicated model and/or more internal knowledge about your system. The steps for solving it as a least squares problem are still the same but the partial derivatives and are the final equation may get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I will have to try out different powers for each input vector such as 
$$
y = w1(x1[n]^{pow})+w2x2+w3x3
$$ 
 and check which one fits the output the most?

Comment: Maybe. It's often best to learn as much about the physic or mechanisms behind the data instead of blindly guessing at a model. For example: if you know that your inputs are spatial co-ordinates you can try something like $y = \sqrt{w_1x_1^2+w_3x_3^2+w_3x_3^2}$